# Fastest way to run Java jar file from Python?

Tags: java, python, performance, optimization

Here's my issue. I have an existing .jar file that I must use in my program. The program, however, is written in Python.

Since my program is taking a long time to run (a named entity tagger on a large development corpus) I profiled it using cProfiler and lined profiled it using line_profiler. It seems that 92% of the time is spent on this task.

I am currently using the following code:

```
import subprocess as sub
sub.call(["java", "-jar", "-Xmx512m", "MyFile.jar", 
         featuresFileName, numIterations, featureCutOff])
```

I read somewhere about subprocess vs Popen and other bits and pieces, but couldn't find a good solution that does not require subprocess or os calls (of course, there may not be any).

I'd really appreciate some advice on the fastest way to run a .jar file from within a Python script. Note, however, that I cannot modify the Java code nor do I have access to speak to the developer of that code.

Alternatively, and I don't know if this will help or if I'm simply grasping at straws here, but perhaps there is a way to keep the process called in `sub.call()` above in the background, somehow keeping the JVM running (?) so that I can simply invoke the jar file. Maybe that can help reduce startup costs? BTW I am a total Java newbie (mostly C++,C#,Python experience) so my question could make no sense whatsoever - I apologize in advance...

Answer (score 3):

You could try porting your Python to Jython, and then run it all natively in the same JVM (that may or may not work). That way you have effectively zero start up time, and the JVM has enough time to leverage its JIT over time to ideally give you better performance overall.

Comment: If you ported it to Jython, I believe you could turn it into a Java native library, like people do with C libraries in CPython and then call it as though it were a Python module.

Answer (score 1):

That indicates that most of the time is spent in this process.  It may not be the startup time which is the problem.  It may be what it does once it has started.

The only way around this I can think of is to run the process in the background, multiple time concurrently if that is an option. (concurrently rather than running one after another)

Comment: I was going in that direction as well... Unfortunately, I have to run it once through each pass of my algorithm and when I realized that I realized I'd have no chance at concurrency.

Comment: It sounds like if you want to make it faster you are going to have to change the Java code. A standard way to improve startup time is to run the jar as a service which you could do by adding  another jar which calls this.  This has the advantage that your service is running all the time (i.e. no startup)

Comment: That is exactly what I just edited my question to ask :) Should have refreshed the page first... I'm going to try it, will post back when I have some results... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with "-client" option. It should reduce JVM startup time.

Answer (score 0):

By analysing the manifest file of the jar file you can find out the class name of the jar file which is used. So then you could in principle write your own small java daemon which is listening for new arguments to arrive and calls the main() function of the appropriate class. But it is really  worth the effort only if startup costs are the issue.